# Traversing a column recursively with 2 pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, recursion

> int* m = new int [d1*d2];   (row*column)

```
for ( j = 0; j < d2; j++ ){
        largest = new int(0);
        for ( i = j; i < d1*d2; i +=d2){
            if ( *(m+i) > *largest){largest = (m+i);}
```

This code finds the greatest element in columns.What i want to do is to keep finding greatest elements in columns recursively by using pointers.

Let's say i've a column like this:

> 7
>
> 6
>
> 5

I find the largest element, 7 in this case, and it is stored in largest.

Now i want a second pointer,let's say

> int* ptr2

And use it to store the 2nd greatest element in my column, 6 in this case and calculate

> *largest +  *ptr2

And do it recursively for 6 and 5(while *largest keeps 6 and *ptr2 keeps 5)

> *largest + *ptr2

I've tried setting initial position on ptr2 to one element below largest by using

> ptr2 = largest + d2

Didn't work properly.Also could be problematic when the largest element is at the bottom of column then this line would set ptr2 to somewhere out of array i guess.

Comment: why don't you sort the column first? It will be easier and will require less computation.

Comment: @perreal It is more expensive to do a sort if you don't want every single largest value, just a small constant number of largest values (`O(nlogn)` vs `O(n*m)` for small m) But if you want most to all of them then you may as well sort. (By the way, to sort to find largest values yet leave the original values in their position, make an array of pointers and compare by `*x` vs `*y`)

Comment: @perreal I don't sort them becouse the order of integers matter in the actual program.I tried to abstract the program as much as i can for the sake of simplicity but i believe the logic is smthlike that.

Comment: @user2362377, if you are going to do this for all such pairs then it is inefficient, i.e., O(n^2)

Comment: @perreal Yeah probably but it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try to compile/run this but as a suggestion:

```
int *largest, *runnerup;
for ( j = 0; j < d2; j++ ){
  int l = 0;
  find_max(m, j, &l, &largest, d2);
  find_max(m, j, largest, &runnerup, d2);
  // do stuff
  largest = runnerup;
}

void find_max(int *mx, int col, int *le, int **max, int d2) {
  max[0] = le;
  for ( i = col; i < d1; i++){
    if (max[0] <= m[i * d2] && max[0] != &m[i * d2]) {
      max[0] = &m[i * d2];
    }
  } 
}
```